# Mac app works fine while running in Xcode, but deployment version crashes

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, macos-big-sur

I recently updated an app I've been releasing since 2012. My latest version works perfectly within xcode, but when I archive to create the distribution, the app will launch, but upon opening a file it crashes every time. I'm on MacOS big sur 11.1. Here's a crash report excerpt.

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT at 0x00000001027ec49c (brk 1)
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [20456]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   JoshLevy.ReasonSync2            0x00000001027ec49c Swift runtime failure: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value + 0 (Document.swift:39) [inlined]
1   JoshLevy.ReasonSync2            0x00000001027ec49c Document.makeWindowControllers() + 628 (Document.swift:39)
2   JoshLevy.ReasonSync2            0x00000001027ec3ec ViewController.playerView.getter + 24 [inlined]
3   JoshLevy.ReasonSync2            0x00000001027ec3ec Document.makeWindowControllers() + 452 (Document.swift:39)
4   JoshLevy.ReasonSync2            0x00000001027ec4c0 @objc Document.makeWindowControllers() + 28
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000198cdfa98 __80-[NSDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.841 + 168
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000198ce920c ___NSMainRunLoopPerformBlockInModes_block_invoke + 44
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000195f8b6c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 28
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000195f8b534 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 408
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000195f8a1d0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000195f89740 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x000000019daa6678 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x000000019daa64a8 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 688
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x000000019daa61d8 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000198761da4 _DPSNextEvent + 868
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000198760724 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1312
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000019875260c -[NSApplication run] + 600
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000198723db0 NSApplicationMain + 1064
18  JoshLevy.ReasonSync2            0x00000001027eaf30 main + 12 (AppDelegate.swift:12)
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000195eacf34 start + 4
```

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring this out - I know exactly where in the code it's crashing - when it's trying to open up a file using a URL. But because I can't replicate this within xcode, I really don't know how to fix it. The offending code seems to be:

```
        self.videoPlayer=AVPlayer.init(url: url)
```

... within the entire class:

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class Document: NSDocument {
     
    var videoPlayer: AVPlayer!
    var lag1 = 0.0

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    override class var autosavesInPlace: Bool {
        return true
    }
        
    override func makeWindowControllers() {
        NSLog("%@", "makeWindowControllers")
        // Returns the Storyboard that contains your Document window.
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: nil)
        let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("Document Window Controller")) as! NSWindowController
        self.addWindowController(windowController)
        let vc = windowController.contentViewController as! ViewController
        vc.playerView.player = self.videoPlayer
        vc.playerView.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    }
    
    override func data(ofType typeName: String) throws -> Data {
        // Insert code here to write your document to data of the specified type, throwing an error in case of failure.
        // Alternatively, you could remove this method and override fileWrapper(ofType:), write(to:ofType:), or write(to:ofType:for:originalContentsURL:) instead.
        throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
    }
    
    override func read(from url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws {
         self.videoPlayer=AVPlayer.init(url: url)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(url, forKey: "lastURL")
        Swift.print("opening",url,typeName)
    }
    
}
```

...which works perfectly fine in xcode...I have entitlements set up for sandbox, user-selected files read/write. (I've also tried removing the sandbox, and it still has the same problem)

Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The AVPlayer initializer should not produce an optional so this line is either failing because url or self are implicitly unwrapped optionals. Can you please provide more context.

Comment: I updated the above with the entire class

Comment: If you really have the same value in `url` when debugging with Xcode and when using the archived version, this might be a bug on Apple's side. Please try these things and see whether a crash occurs: 1) Compile and debug with optimizations. 2) Create an archive without optimizations. 3) Make videoPlayer an explicit optional. 4) Unoptionalize videoPlayer and initialize it to something inline.

Comment: for (3) do you mean like: ```var videoPlayer: AVPlayer?```

Comment: Yes that’s what I meant.

Comment: Ok doing everything you mention, I still get the same exact result - still crashing - but ONLY after archiving: still works fine in xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing - but for some reason, the AVKit and AVFoundation libraries disappeared from the "build phases" pane. I only noticed this after trying to duplicate the project - basically starting from scratch. For some reason this did not stop the app from running within xcode.

After adding in the 2 libraries, the app worked outside of xcode as well. So this is closed.